# Grouping sets size cannot be greater than 64 : Hive

Tags: hive

I have 70 columns in my hive table i want to fetch all the rows which have exactly all the 70 matching columns.i.e. if two rows contain same data in all the column then i need to find that row and count as '2'. I'm writing below query.

```
    SELECT (all 70 columns),COUNT(*) AS CountOf FROM tablename GROUP BY (all 70 columns) 
    HAVING  COUNT(*)>1;
```

but its showing

```
    Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10411]: 
    Grouping sets size cannot be 
    greater than 64 (state=42000,code=10411)
```

is there any way to find the exact duplicate rows's count from hive table?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug [HIVE-21135](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-21135) in Hive `3.1.0` version, it is fixed in the Hive `4.0.0`, see [HIVE-21018](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-21018), not backported.

Try to concatenate columns using delimiter in the subquery before aggregation as a workaround, I'm not sure will it help or not.

like this, using concat() or concat_ws or `||` operator:

```
select concat_ws ('~', col1, col2, col3, col4)
...
group by concat_ws ('~', col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

or

```
col1||'~'||col2||'~'||...||colN
```

NULLs should be taken care also. Replace nulls with empty strings before concatenation using NVL function.